# ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequential' from 'keras.models'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, theano

I have installed keras followed by tensorflow.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
```

When I execute keras sequential model, I get an error message stating that

> Import Error Trackback (most recent call last)
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequential' from 'keras.models' (C:\Users\murthy.p\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda4\lib\site-packages\keras\models__init__.py)

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, if you're importing more than one thing from say `keras.models` or `keras.layers` put them on one line.

For this specific problem, try importing it from tensorflow which is essentially the keras API. I'm quite confident it should work!

`from tensorflow.keras import Sequential`

To install tensorflow: `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0`

Comment: 4 hours of installation issues and this "pip install" command is fixed the issue within minutes (inside the Anaconda console). Amen to this solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't install keras properly you can install it in the command line of the environment you are using by applying the following code

```
pip install keras
```