# ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequential' in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have installed Keras with Tensorflow and basically I can import tensorflow in Juyper Notebook. However, when I want to import the Sequential class I get an error message stating:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequential'

This is my code that I use:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
```

I found this question in Stackoverflow [ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequential' from 'keras.models'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388162/importerror-cannot-import-name-sequential-from-keras-models) but it did not help. Does anyone of you have an idea, why this problem occurs? I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: works for me with `tf.__version__ 2.3.0`

Comment: @PeterBe What's your TF version? As of 2.4.1 this should work. The docs are here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential

Comment: Thanks for your answers. When I use the code "print(tf.__version__)" then I get the error "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'". So I can't tell you which tensorflow version I use

Comment: I just looked into Anaconda and there it says that my tensorflow version is 2.1.0

Answer (score 3):

Sequential() lives in `tensorflow.keras.models`.

You would have to do
`from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ArcKoor. When using your suggested code I get the error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.models'; 'tensorflow.keras' is not "

Comment: Without your version it's hard to help. Press Windows+r and type in cmd. If you have installed using conda, type conda activate [your environment name] and then conda list. If you have installed with pip then pip list should be enough. Then scroll down until you see tensorflow and tell us what number stands next to it.

Comment: I just looked into Anaconda and there it says that my tensorflow version is 2.1.0

Comment: Exact same version I'm running, so im really not sure where that comes from. Can you import stuff like `tensorflow.keras.layers`?

Comment: Now I am currently updating the tensorflow with "pip install tensorflow --upgrade" in Anaconda.

Comment: Now it seems to work. I think there was a problem with Anaconda. This happens quite often with Anaconda that some packages just don't work after a while (I do not know the reason for that). But still thanks for your help. I upvoted your answer